# why is this test case failing even though both the functions in assertEqual are returning the same value?

Tags: python, unit-testing

why the test case is failing even though both of the functions return the same vaule ?

```
import unittest

def first():
    return 4312
def second():
    return 4312

class testcase(unittest.TestCase):
    def case1(self):
        self.assertEqual(first(),second())


def test():
    print first(),second()
    unittest.main()
```

I am executing the test() function

### and the output i am getting is :

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    test()
  File "C:/Users/ashutosh.rd/Desktop/x.py", line 15, in test
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 231, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: False
```

Comment: Works for me, although I had to edit this script to get it to run as a test. Please edit to include an actual script that works, and the full results of running this script.

Comment: How exactly is it failing? What are you running, and what is python giving back that is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your test case isn't running because the method in your test case needs to start with the letters "test" (e.g., "test_me()") to be identified as a test case. Change the name of case1 to test1, and your test will run.

Comment: i am getting the same error even if I name the function as test_case1

Comment: So you still get "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s"?

Comment: Something else is wrong.
When I run your code, changing "case1" to "test_case1" under Python 2.7.1, I get everything passing:
4312 4312
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK